# VBA - Sharepoint Check-out and Check-in a non-excel file

Tags: vba, sharepoint

## Problem

Excel VBA offers means to CheckOut and CheckIn Excel workbooks as follows:

```vb
if workbooks.CanCheckOut(sFile) then
   workbook.CheckOut(sFile)
   set wb = workbooks.open(sFile)

   'make changes

   wb.CheckIn true, "Some comment", true
end if
```

However if I am trying to check out a text file (or any other for that matter), How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [sharepoint library](https://github.com/sancarn/VBA-STD-Library/blob/master/src/WIP/stdSharepointSite.cls).

To check out/in a file:

```
Dim sp as stdSharepointSite
set sp = stdSharepointSite.Create("teams","http://teams/wholesale/Leicester", "myUser", "myPass")

if sp.CheckOutFile("http://teams/wholesale/Leicester/myFile.txt", false) then
   'Can and have checked out
   'Do stuff
   
   if thereAreChanges then
       'save file to sharepoint
       '...

       'check in changes
       sp.CheckInFile("http://teams/wholesale/Leicester/myFile.txt", "Updated my file")
   else
       'Discard checkout
       sp.CheckOutDiscard("http://teams/wholesale/Leicester/myFile.txt")
   end if
else
    'Cannot checkout...
end if
```